# Performance when using phrases in MongoDB text search

Tags: mongodb, full-text-search, database-performance, text-search

I observe worse performance than I expected when using phrases in MongoDB's text search.

Given the following MongoDB text index that contains next to other data phone numbers stored in international [E.123 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E.123): e.g. `+49 12 345678` (be aware of the spaces).
[image: Studio3T screenshot of text index]

When I perform a query looking up a phone number in international E.123 format then MongoDB identifies 3 tokens `+49`, `12` and `345678` and the explain shows me that it does three lookups which gets combined. -> this makes sense.
[image: Explain of simple search]

---

***But now comes my problem: I want to lookup a particular number and query for a single phrase by quoting the whole phone number: `"+49 12 345678"`.***

Even that I search for a single phrase MongoDB seems to perform 3 lookups, which still makes sense to me. But it performs a `union + deduplicate` and loads the data of `697MB` before identifying that there is no result. I think the `union + deduplication` step could be an `intersection` step and could identify that the outcome will be `0` documents. Then it wouldn't need to load any data.
[image: Explain of phrase search]

Is there any way to tell MongoDB to perform an `intersection` instead of a `union`?
In my case it makes a difference in performance in production: `1 second vs 8 seconds` in real queries.

My setup: MongoDB `4.4.6`

Comment: A phrase query in Atlas Search seems like a good fit for this type of query, but it appears you are not using Atlas. Is that a possibility? There is a free tier.

Comment: @Nice-Guy yes, I am running MongoDB 4.4.6 on-premise and moving to the cloud is not an option for my use-case.